# Website Refreshes After Clicking Button JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

When Clicking A specific Button, (Submit) the page Refreshes, I really don't want It to refresh, What can I do?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

@someone It's always advisable to add proper description on your question with relevant code snippet or some demo. It gives better understanding to answer other question.

As far I understand with your question you may try below solution if you are still looking for solution:

1. As suggested in previous answer, remove action attribute if it's not in use.
2. Make input type button instead submit
3. use `javascript.void()` in action attribute.

If you query yet not resolved with above solution then request you to please provide some information. Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

When you are clicking a input button type of 'Submit' it will refresh the page at it is submitting an action - in this case login to 'login.html'.

If you wanted to open the link in a new page you would have to add attribute `target="_blank"` to your tag. As in:

`<input type="submit" name="" value="login" target="_blank">`

The reason you may be showing an error is due to an incorrect link within `<script src="link2.js"></script>`.

Use console within developer tools to identify where it may be going wrong.

Answer (score -3):

Remove action attribute from form

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/32432363)

Comment: This is exactly the answer to the question

Comment: This is a comment not an aswer

Comment: To fix the issue OP should remove the action attribute from the form tag. How is it a comment not an answer when it solves the issue?